# How to serve gzip compressed file in rails 7.0.x and ruby 3.1.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-assets

I am using webpack plugin "compression-webpack-plugin" which created .js.gz files for app-bundle and vendor-bundle

How can I use gz files in asset precompile so my **application.js** size can be decreased?

The current Size is 10MB gz file size is of 2 MB

**Application.js**

```
//= require vendor-bundle.js.gz
//= require app-bundle.js.gz
```

If I try to use this i am getting an error

> Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'app-bundle.js.gz' with
> type 'application/javascript'

Configuration

assets.rb

```
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'webpack')
```

Rails.application.config.assets.precompile +=
[
"application.js",
%w(fullWidthContainer.js IEAlertScript.js carousel.js))
]

**Production.rb**

```
config.assets.js_compressor = :terser
config.assets.css_compressor = :sass
config.assets.compile = false
```

How can we use js.gz in precompile so file size can be reduced?

Comment: I think you're just confused here. Gzip compressions is usually handled on the server level  (as in NGinX or Apache)- usually by whatever CDN you're using to serve the assets in production. You don't actually need or want to GZIP the asset files themselves.

Comment: Spend your time instead on figuring out how to actually meaningfully reduce the size of your assets files for example by auditng dependencies.